# Can having many windows accounts slow down your computer?

Tags: windows

I know that every account uses some space, but beside that, is it slowing down computer in some other way?

I have windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way it would impact performance (other than the disk space as you mentioned) is if more than one user is logged on to the machine at the same time, like when a "Switch User" is done, which pushes all User A's running processes (using RAM and CPU) to the background essentially so the new User B can then log on.